# continues hover color over border spacing table

Tags: html, css, html-table

My table has `border-collapse: seperate;` and `border-spacing: 50px 0;`.

Upon hover, the whole row bg changes.
Issue is, the empty area of the `border-spacing` doesn't change.
I can use `padding` instead of `boeder-spacing`, however i have borders and background colors over the columns, so padding won't change them but just make the cells bigger.
So the result must have seperated cells with seperated borders but upon hover the whole row background must be equal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: seperate;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 50px 0;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;

}

.second-row {
background: red;
}

tr:hover {background-color: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<colgroup><col><col class="second-row"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1La49rf/)

Comment: Can you link your example where you use padding and explain why that doesn't work for you?  Seems a much simpler solution.

Comment: @Dave please review my comment to the post below, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think you will need to add a span or div into the middle column to provide the spacing instead of using the border-spacing because of the background colour on hover.

```
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th><span>Last Name</span></th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;

}

tr:hover {background-color: yellow;}
tr:hover span {background-color: yellow;}

span {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hdtgomr3/

The layout is very similar but the background colour on hover is able to be applied to the whole row without the border-spacing.

**Edit**: updated link and added hover and padding property to code snippet to ensure background colour is changed across the whole row without gaps.

Alternatively, use empty cells for the empty looking columns: https://jsfiddle.net/8uemtj0x/22/

Comment: thank you, Please notice 2 issues:
1.Upon hover, the colored row bg won't change.
2.The border is cut between each row (small cuts)

Comment: Ah yes I see, I've updated this https://jsfiddle.net/02apjs49/3/  1. add `tr:hover span` to change the hover background to be the same as the `tr:hover`; 2. a padding property on the `th,tr` seems to fix the cuts between each row. Hope that helps.

Comment: @E.J Please edit your answer to this changing, to vote for you and be excepted:)

Comment: @E.J thanks very much.

Comment: No worries @orahl! @ArmanEbrahimi thanks, I've updated the answer :)

Comment: @E.J The issue still remains when making a cell bigger, try to change the first name head cell into 2 rows (with <br> for example), the other head cells will now have white spacing between each one of them. Do you have any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: You might have to add `height:100%` to the span, cell and table like this https://jsfiddle.net/8uemtj0x/8/. Or another way could be to use empty cells: https://jsfiddle.net/8uemtj0x/22/

Comment: @orahl  using extra empty cells seems to work well with minimal CSS changes, so that might be a good way to go instead. The only problem is that you have to add empty cells to all the rows. But hopefully one of those solutions will help!