# HTML/JAVASCRIPT ondragleave fired when moving between child objects

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the behaviour of the javascript 'ondragleave' that is fired between child elements.

See the example with some simple code.

The problem is that the records would not stay red between the two TD elements, although the mouse is still dragging in the TR record.

There are some answers that include counters, but non of them seems to make is possible to work

```js
function enter(ev, recordid) {
  document.getElementById(recordid).style.backgroundColor = '#AA0000';
}

function leave(ev, recordid) {
  document.getElementById(recordid).style.backgroundColor = '';
}
```

```html
<p draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>

<table width=100% style='border-spacing: 30px;'>
  <tr id='record1' ondragenter='enter(event, this.id);' ondragleave='leave(event, this.id);'>
    <td>Record 1-1</td>
    <td>Record 1-2</td>
    <td>Record 1-3</td>
    <td>Record 1-4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='record2' ondragenter='enter(event, this.id);' ondragleave='leave(event, this.id);'>
    <td>Record 2-1</td>
    <td>Record 3-2</td>
    <td>Record 4-3</td>
    <td>Record 5-4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So the question is `how to colour a row when hovering over the border spacing`

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568050/continues-hover-color-over-border-spacing-table

Comment: Does this have anything to do with `ondragleave`? Appears to be a CSS issue.

Comment: It looks like the ondragleave is called when moving the dragging from one TD, to another TD, on the same TR. Logically this should not work because you are still moving in the same tr. The extra spacing is there to make the problem seen sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your issue:

> problem is that the records would not stay red between the two TD elements

This can be solved with CSS & has nothing to do with `ondragleave`:

```js
function enter(ev, recordid) {
  document.getElementById(recordid).style.backgroundColor = '#AA0000';
}

function leave(ev, recordid) {
  document.getElementById(recordid).style.backgroundColor = '';
}
```

```html
<style>
  td { padding: 0px; }
  table { width: 100%; border-spacing: 0px; }
</style>

<p draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!</p>

<table>
  <tr id='record1' ondragenter='enter(event, this.id);' ondragleave='leave(event, this.id);'>
    <td>Record 1-1</td>
    <td>Record 1-2</td>
    <td>Record 1-3</td>
    <td>Record 1-4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='record2' ondragenter='enter(event, this.id);' ondragleave='leave(event, this.id);'>
    <td>Record 2-1</td>
    <td>Record 3-2</td>
    <td>Record 4-3</td>
    <td>Record 5-4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately.  If you dray the "Drag me" to Records 1-1, to Records 1-2, the full row is disabled.